# Pictures are only reduced when width: 100%;

Tags: html, css

**Why do I need to add width?**

*I have 3 blocks on the page with my pictures and text. If I write these styles in CSS -*

```
.facilities{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.facilities-col{
    flex-basis: 31%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: left;
}
.facilities-col img{
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

*They don't shrink down to the standard 100vh. But if I add:*

```
.facilities-col img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

*, they will fit evenly and sloppily on the site.*

*Here is an example of 1 block*

```
<div class="facilities-col">
    <img src="images/library.png">
    <h3>World Class Library</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pallentesque aliquet turpis nulla.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So , what is your question ?

Comment: thats what they should do, use `max-width: 100%;` if you dont want them to scale up

Comment: Where is your `flexbox`? `flex-basis` is a property that goes into flexbox items.

Comment: What do you mean "shrink down" to 100vh?

Comment: Could you reformat your code into a snippet that we can run to check the output?